# in using print and DIct

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, printf

```
def sum_server_use_time(Server):
    total_use_time = 0.0
    for key,value in Server.items():
                total_use_time += Server[key]
    return round(total_use_time, 2) 
    if total_use_time !=898:
        print(total_use_time)
FileServer = {"EndUser1": 2.25, "EndUser2": 4.5, "EndUser3": 1, "EndUser4": 3.75, "EndUser5": 0.6, "EndUser6": 8}
(sum_server_use_time(FileServer)) # Should print 20.1
```

I am getting no answer what did I do wrong here can anyone explain me please I am frustrated over this problem, and can you list the topics I need to be perfect to understand such problems

Comment: You `print` after the return, try printing your function return value instead maybe ?

Comment: You can directly sum values of `dict` using `sum(Server.values())`  and like @GregoireDucharme said, maybe print before or after return value.

Comment: You should master the basics really, look at `for key,value in Server.items():` you already have `value` but still use `Server[key]` to grab it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_server_use_time(Server):
    total_use_time = 0.0
    for key, value in Server.items():
        total_use_time += Server[key]
    if total_use_time != 898:
        print(total_use_time)
    return round(total_use_time, 2)


def main():
    FileServer = {"EndUser1": 2.25, "EndUser2": 4.5, "EndUser3": 1, "EndUser4": 3.75, "EndUser5": 0.6, "EndUser6": 8}
    print(sum_server_use_time(FileServer))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It seems you want to print and return the same value:

```py
    print(total_use_time)
return round(total_use_time, 2)
```

You could get rid of the print or the return. However since you function is called `sum_server_use_time` you should stick to that.

The function should only sum the times, so let's modify the function to do ONLY that.

```
def sum_server_use_time(Server):
    total_use_time = 0.0
    for key, value in Server.items():
        total_use_time += Server[key]
    return round(total_use_time, 2)
```

Then outside the function we can work with the result:

```
FileServer = {"EndUser1": 2.25, "EndUser2": 4.5, "EndUser3": 1, "EndUser4": 3.75, "EndUser5": 0.6, "EndUser6": 8}
total_use_time = sum_server_use_time(FileServer)
if total_use_time != 898:
    print(total_use_time)
```

Final code:

```py
def sum_server_use_time(Server):
    total_use_time = 0.0
    for key, value in Server.items(): # Here you already have value
        total_use_time += Server[key] # But you still grab it using Server[key]
    return round(total_use_time, 2)


def main():
    FileServer = {"EndUser1": 2.25, "EndUser2": 4.5, "EndUser3": 1, "EndUser4": 3.75, "EndUser5": 0.6, "EndUser6": 8}
    total_use_time = sum_server_use_time(FileServer)
    if total_use_time != 898:
        print(total_use_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And for the super-short answer:

Dictionaries have a method called `.values()` that return a list of, well, values.

So you can do `round(sum(FileServer.values()),2)` and still get 20.1